# How to compare two lists of lists in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, compare

I am using two different dataframes:

```
      Project, Paragraph, Articles
df1 = 18PR001, 001, [A, B, C, D, E, F]
      18PR002, 001, [A, C]
      18PR002, 002, [A, D, E, F]
      ...    , ..., ...
 
      Recipe, Articles
df2 = 9801, [A, B, C]
      9802, [A, C]
      9803, [A, D, E]
      ... , ...
```

I want the recipes which have simular articles in df1 to be appended as a new list to a new df, so like this:

```
      Project, Paragraph, Recipe
df3 = 18PR001, 001, [9801, 9802, 9803]
      18PR002, 001, [9802]
      18PR002, 002, [9803]
      ...    , ..., ...
```

I found some answers based on comparing two lists of lists, but the other information in the dataframes are essential as well. What would you advise me to do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any criteria for Articles in the 2 dataframes to be regarded as a match ?  60% items in list got matched ?   This has to be determined beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment SeaBean. Paulo Guerra already gave the solution and I was able to use 95% as a treshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the records on both `DataFrames` by exploding their lists of articles and then merging them into a third dataset, as the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Project': ['18PR001', '18PR002', '18PR002'],
                    'Paragraph': ['001', '001', '002'],
                    'Articles': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                                 ['A', 'C'],
                                 ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Recipe': [9801, 9802, 9803],
                    'Articles': [['A', 'B', 'C'],
                                 ['A', 'C'],
                                 ['A', 'D', 'E']]})


df3 = pd.merge(df2.explode('Articles'), df1.explode('Articles'), on='Articles')
```

To get any matches you can then simply `groupby()` and apply a `list()` to them:

```
df3.groupby(['Project', 'Paragraph'])['Recipe'].apply(list)
```

Or to retrieve unique matches:

```
df3.groupby(['Project', 'Paragraph'])['Recipe'].unique().apply(list)
```

The problem with this code is that it retrieves any matches among the common articles, as SeaBean kindly remarked previously.

An alternative would be counting the number of matches and normalizing the result

```
df3.groupby(['Project', 'Paragraph'])['Recipe'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True))
```

The output of this last chunk of code is:

```
Project  Paragraph      
18PR001  001        9803    0.375
                    9801    0.375
                    9802    0.250
18PR002  001        9802    0.400
                    9801    0.400
                    9803    0.200
         002        9803    0.600
                    9802    0.200
                    9801    0.200
```

You can then set a threshold to consider two items similar (i.e. 60%) and filter the data, you can retrieve the maximum per group applying `max()`, or even the `nlargest()`.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Didn't think of doing it in this way, but it brought me the result I wanted. Thank you very much, your help is highly appreciated!